# persisting request String to Database in symfony2 fails?

Tags: php, database, entity-framework, symfony

First, I have a form that submits some strings to my controller. This controller first access the corresponding entity in the database and then tries to update those strings for that entity.

I retrieve the parameters as follows:

```
$message = $request->request->get('message');
```

for testing purposes i put in this line:

```
echo '<script>alert("the message is: ' . $message . '");</script>';
```

it alerts the expected message -> so i go ahead and assume that the $message variable actually "makes it" to my controller correctly.

Next, I update the entity information:

```
$entity->setMessage($message);
```

This results in an empty value in the database. No error, no crashing server, `$message` just never reaches its destiny.
My next assumption was that the entity function setMessage might have a problem and so i used (string) casting wherever possible in every possible combination.

Next, I put a `var_dump` everywhere, again all combinations possible. And even the entity-attribute message put out`"string(x)" xxxx`

So I thought "well it gets assigned correctly"

So far I would assume I probably forgot

```
$em->persist($entity);

$em->flush();
```

But even that I seemed to have remembered to put in.

So I thought of a new test. I created a new variable called $test, assigned some random string to it and called setMessage with this one, naturally assuming this couldn't possibly work. It did. It got persisted smoothly.

To sum it up: I get the correct entity, the strings are loaded and actually exist correctly within the controller, the entity methods work perfectly, the entity manager persists and flushes just the way I want it.

What is wrong here? The only difference between my `$test` string and `$message` string I can determine is that `$message` comes from a request. It seems thats where my knowledge of the matter is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. I seems to be a universal problem solver actually. Shut down computer, go home, come back next day, it works.

Given the circumstances I believe there had to be some sort of browser/symfony cache problem/bug/error-on-my-behalf that had $message stored from a previous execution of the controller and failed to properly clear it. Even though the $message string always correctly reached the controller, it never got persisted. So either (if it is a cache problem) $message got cached somewhere on the way from the controller to the entity method / in the entity itself or the entity manager itself had a cached version of the entity and used it whenever $message was used.

That is the explanation I came up with. if someone has an educated guess or actually knows what happened please let me know.